Why does my 14 month old baby wakes up crying asking for water and banana in the night
I exclusively breastfed my baby and he sleeps with us. Needs my touch. Wakes up 3-4 times. 3 times for water once for banana now it is a habit.

At 14 months, a baby may need more food than just mothers milk. Have you already started giving solids?

Yes he eats the same food as i do less spicy and salty

Salty might be why he wakes up thirsty. Check the recommended daily amount of salt for your child's age to see if you're exceeding it. Also, it's probably not the best idea to feed a child salty food from a lifelong taste preference point of view.

@anongoodnurse I suppose "less spicy and salty" means "less spicy and less salty," don't you think?

Bananas, specifically? Is he a fan of the Minions?

@phoog - If your only comments concern someone's grammar, they aren't very helpful, are they? (I've noticed you do this, e.g. "Did you see "can be" near the beginning of the first sentence?" Why?) There's no reason to add any salt to a baby's food, and every reason not to.

@anongoodnurse the purpose of my comment was to point out that yours seems to have been based on a misreading of the question.  If it was not, i.e., if you understood "less salty" but wanted to address the possibility that "less salty" might still mean too much salt, then it's probably a good idea to bring that to light so others don't discount your comment altogether as I nearly did.

@phoog - "Less salty" is still salty, don't you think? It's just less so. Arguing I "misunderstood" based on your interpretation of grammar is a lazy argument and much less dignified than just not commenting. My comment stands. Your comment is not only inaccurate, it's irrelevant.

Make sure your child is drinking plenty in the day, offering milk (breast or otherwise) and water often and refilling their cup/bottle often.
Also make sure that your child's pre-bedtime meal is going to keep them going all night, including protein (animal or plant based), fat and fibre. Maybe swap to brown rice/bread or add a nice thick yoghurt for dessert.
If they do wake up thirsty, and well, we all do sometimes if it's hot or we have a cold for example. A few sips of water and then cuddle back to sleep. I'd keep a suitable sippy cup of water close and keep any wakeups quiet and calm.
I often found we'd get a bad patch of sleep which would last a week or two, maybe coinciding with a growth spurt or a new development in my child, and he'd go back to sleeping better once he was done developing.

I would also consider the timing of the pre-bedtime meal. If dinner is say 2 hours before bed-time plus 10 hours of sleep, then 12 hours without food is a long time for a 14-months old. Maybe add another snack just before bed-time.
